# Is there a way to disable usage of cached feature types in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

Because of thread locking issue connected with code which  locks threads when working with cached feature types I would like to disable this feature. Root issue [GeoServer 2.9.2 database connection pooling/thread locking issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268900/geoserver-2-9-2-database-connection-pooling-thread-locking-issue)

Comment: If it is the same issue as in the provided link, then just adjust the number of connections as suggested...

Comment: Looking for a way to avoid reaching certain synchronised block of code

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the size of the FeatureTypeCache on the [global settings page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#feature-type-cache-size).

But make sure you have read and understood the rest of the paragraph.

> The cache size should generally be greater than the number of distinct featuretypes that are expected to be accessed simultaneously. If possible, make this value larger than the total number of featuretypes on the server, but a setting too high may produce out-of-memory errors. On the other hand, a value lower than the total number of your registered featuretypes may clear and reload the resource-cache more often, which can be expensive and e.g. delay WFS-Requests in the meantime. The default value for the Feature type cache size is 100

Comment: I do know about it's size adjustment parameter, was wondering about possibility to turn it off completely just to see what happens.

Comment: set it to 0 then

Comment: Didn't delve too much into the code but will it stop synchronization on `featureTypeCache` https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/63e47fc00f93234d8e3957a6760f7f10baddef8a/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/catalog/ResourcePool.java#LC940 ?

Comment: no idea, you'll need to try it and see